# How can the Vector Magnetic Potential be defined in both the regions where current density is equal and non-equal to zero?

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields, maxwell-equations

I am currently reading about the steady magnetic field, and when I came across the vector magnetic potential I came to know that it can be defined in both the regions where current density $\mathbf J = 0$ and $\mathbf J\neq 0$ unlike the scalar magnetic potential where the current density $\mathbf J$ must be zero throughout the region in which the it is defined.

So my question is, **how can we show that the vector magnetic potential can be defined in both the regions where $\mathbf J=0$ and $\mathbf J\neq 0$ ?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an explicit way to see why $\vec{A}$ is defined at all points.

The vector potential $\vec{A}$ is given by the following:
$$\vec{A}(\vec{r},t)=\int d^3r’ \frac{\mu_0}{4\pi}\frac{\vec{J}(\vec{r}’,t)}{\big| \vec{r}-\vec{r}’\big|}$$
As is evident from the RHS of the above equation, the vector potential at a point is a result of integrating over all points in space. Thus it doesn’t matter if $\vec{J}$ is zero or not at some point(s).

Answer (score 1):

I think you can agree that the magnetic field $\mathbf B$ can be defined in regions where $\mathbf J$ is $0$ (think of the field around a current carrying wire). Since the vector potential $\mathbf A$ relates to the magnetic field by

$$\mathbf B=\nabla\times\mathbf A$$

the curl of $\mathbf A$ must also be able to be defined in regions where $\mathbf J=0$, which means $\mathbf A$ must also be able to be defined in these regions.

Answer (score 0):

Maxwell's equation $\textrm{curl} \textbf{E}=-\frac {\partial\textbf{B}}{\partial t}$ is true irrespective of the current, hence you always have $\textrm{div}\frac {\partial\textbf{B}}{\partial t}= \frac {\partial}{\partial t} \textrm{div}\textbf{B}=0$ hence $\textrm{div}\textbf{B}=constant-of-time$. But we also know that $\textrm{div}\textbf{B}=0$ *always* because there are *no* free magnetic charges hence there is always a vector field $\textbf{A}$ such that $\textbf{B} = \textrm{curl} \textbf{A}$ irrespective of the electric current.